Is tint2's "Hide tasks from different monitors" option always on?
I just recently started using tint2/Openbox through Archcraft, and I'm liking it a lot so far. But there's one little thing I want to configure, and it seems like tint2 is capable of doing this, but perhaps the implementation is bugged, or perhaps I am misunderstanding how this works. I come from Windows mainly, and I wanted to mirror some of the things I liked about the UX on Windows, and one thing in particular is how multi-monitor behavior is handled on the taskbars.
In Windows, with multiple monitors up, you can see every desktop task from across both of them. Now, it appears that there are multiple settings embedded in tint2 to handle this. I've checked both the tint2rc file itself and the configuration tool for tint2 and they both seem to imply this.
The line taskbar_hide_different_monitor = 0 in the tint2rc file would appear to be the setting for this. It is set to 0 by default already, yet despite this, it does not appear to work as such in this screenshot. The tasks on my right monitor only appear on the right monitor's taskbar, not on the left.

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of this particular line on the configuration, is this simply something unsupported by tint2, or is this type of setting possible through a different setting? I'd like to get this solved, since it's really my only nitpick with tint2. Thanks!

Do not post images when plain text will do.

My apologies, but I do feel the taskbar screenshot is necessary to show what it is I'm talking about. I edited the config screenshot out.
